# Quickswap transaction always reverts when using swapExactTokensForTokens

Tags: solidity, uniswap, pancakeswap, polygon, hardhat-deploy

```
pragma solidity 0.7.5;

import "@uniswap/v2-periphery/contracts/interfaces/IUniswapV2Router02.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC20/ERC20.sol";

contract Swap {

    address private constant QUICKSWAP_ROUTER_ADDRESS = 0xa5E0829CaCEd8fFDD4De3c43696c57F7D7A678ff;
    address private constant USDC_MUM_POLY_ADDRESS = 0x2791Bca1f2de4661ED88A30C99A7a9449Aa84174;

    IUniswapV2Router02 private quickSwapRouter = IUniswapV2Router02(QUICKSWAP_ROUTER_ADDRESS);

    function convertEthToUsdc() external payable {
        require(msg.value > 0, "Cannot handle 0 ETH");


        uint256 amountOutMin = 0;
        uint256 deadline = block.timestamp + 15;

        address[] memory path = new address[](2);
        path[0] = quickSwapRouter.WETH();
        path[1] = USDC_MUM_POLY_ADDRESS;


        quickSwapRouter.swapExactETHForTokens{value: msg.value}(
            amountOutMin,
            path,
            msg.sender,
            deadline
        );
    }

    function swapExactTokensForTokensProxy() external payable {
        require(msg.value > 0, "Cannot handle 0 ETH");

        ERC20(quickSwapRouter.WETH()).increaseAllowance(QUICKSWAP_ROUTER_ADDRESS, msg.value);

        address[] memory path = new address[](2);
        path[0] = quickSwapRouter.WETH();
        path[1] = USDC_MUM_POLY_ADDRESS;

        uint256 amountOutMin = 0;
        uint256 deadline = block.timestamp + 15;
        uint256 amountIn = msg.value;
        address to = msg.sender;

        swapExact(amountIn, amountOutMin, path, to, deadline);
    }

    function swapExact(uint256 amountIn, uint256 amountOutMin, 
        address[] memory path, address to, uint256 deadline) internal {
        quickSwapRouter.swapExactTokensForTokens(amountIn, amountOutMin, path, to, deadline);
    }
}
```

Above the solidity code, I'm using to convert the funds sent by the user to USDC.
I'm using hardhat. Below is the deploy script. But the deployment always fails.

Txn :: https://polygonscan.com/tx/0x1b5fb063da9ef32aa32981bbf4e28924a53019e6b851bc1d254154c2eb18064e

```
async function main() {
   // Grab the contract factory
   const Swap = await ethers.getContractFactory("Swap");

   // Start deployment
   const swap = await Swap.deploy(); // Instance of the contract
   console.log("Contract deployed to address:", swap.address);

   const accounts = await hre.ethers.getSigners();
   const signer = accounts[0];

   //console.log("accounts", accounts);
   const swapContract = new ethers.Contract(swap.address, Swap.interface, signer);

   let transactionResponse = await swapContract.swapExactTokensForTokensProxy({value: 1000000000000000, from: accounts[0].address});
}

main()
  .then(() => process.exit(0))
  .catch(error => {
    console.error(error);
    process.exit(1);
  });
```

Can someone please help to debug the issue? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

From the [transaction trace](https://polygonscan.com/vmtrace?txhash=0x1b5fb063da9ef32aa32981bbf4e28924a53019e6b851bc1d254154c2eb18064e&type=gethtrace2) the contract makes calls to two contracts.

The first is to the `WETH()` function at `0xa5e0829caced8ffdd4de3c43696c57f7d7a678ff`. It is successful and returns WMATIC contract.

The second one is to the `increaseAllowance(..)` function at `0x0d500b1d8e8ef31e21c99d1db9a6444d3adf1270`. It doesn't revert but the output value is empty `0x`, it should have returned a bool (32 bytes after ABI encoding).

Solidity now check the returned data size matches the declaration, since it doesn't match 0 versus the 32 expected it reverts.

Looking at WMATIC verified contract it doesn't implement `increaseAllowance(..)`. To make the contract work you have to use `approve(..)` instead.

Comment: how to understand the txn trace. Could you please suggest some sources which can explain the same. Thanks.

Comment: @PalakondaShivaPrasad Sorry, but I don't have any documentation. I've learned how to use it by answering questions here. If you know how solidity works at low level you'll be able to understand the trace.